# Как сделать задержка между прыжками в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хчу сделать механику прыжка для корабля. Корабль может двигаться только по оси x, при прыжке должен подниматься по оси y и останавливаться. Как запретить отрицательное движение по оси y?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float force = 100;

    private Rigidbody2D phys;

    private void Start()
    {
        phys = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        phys.AddForce(new Vector2(0, force));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы корабль не мог двигаться вниз по оси Y можно использовать функцию `Mathf.Clamp()` чтобы не давать упасть скорости корабля ниже нуля

```cs
void FixedUpdate() {
    phys.velocity = new Vector2(phys.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(phys.velocity.y, 0f, 
    Mathf.Infinity));
}
```